# Mogenerator error on deleting a core data object attribute

Tags: xcode, core-data, mogenerator

I'm using xcode 5 and mogenerator. I get a code generation error from mogenerator if I delete a certain attribute from an object in my model. I can delete other attributes from this object as well as delete other attributes from other objects with no problems.

The error is:

```
Assertion failed: (relationship), function -[NSEntityDescription(customBaseClass) _resolveKeyPathType:], file /Users/wolf/code/github/mogenerator/mogenerator.m, line 182.
```

The object in the model is:

[image]

The problem attribute is the highlighted one, permanentID, which is configured as a non-optional int32 with a default of 0.

Just changing the spelling of the name gives the mogenerator build error. The error remains if I version the model and delete the attribute in the new version. I've seen that this error has been associated with fetches involving a variable, but I don't think that's the case here. I have reinstalled both mogenerator and xcode but the error persists.

Can anyone help me identify what the problem is?

Comment: Problem solved. The reported fetch problem was the clue. I had a fetch involving this attribute embedded in the model.

Comment: Please enter this resolution as an answer, and mark it accepted, so that this question doesn't show up as open.